# Use another solver() as input

Tags: python, z3

I want to use existing `solver()` as input. For example , i have three solver:

```
Tie, Shirt = Bools('Tie Shirt')
s_one = Solver()
s_one.add(Or(Tie, Shirt))
s_two = Solver()
s_two.add(Or(Not(Tie), Shirt))
s_three = Solver()
s_three.add(Or(Not(Tie), Not(Shirt)))
```

Now i want to combine all the solver to something like this :
(this script doesn't work, just to show what i meant)

```
s_four = Solver()
s_four.add(s_one, Or(s_two, s_three))
```

How do i do something like that ?

Comment: Well, what is the rule that tells you how to combine the `s_one` result with the `Or(s_two, s_three)` result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The question does make sense in the case of an SMT solver. The rule that tells you how to combine them is in a sense the "meta" conjunction and disjunction of the assertions in each one of these solvers. This is an odd thing to do for an end-user program, but I can imagine a library built on top of z3 might need facilities of this sort.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an odd thing to do, since you already know what the assertions you're adding are. But I can imagine scenarios where you have solvers coming from different parts of the program, or if you are building a library on top of z3 itself.

To achieve what you want, use the `assertions` method:

```py
from z3 import *

Tie, Shirt = Bools('Tie Shirt')
s_one = Solver()
s_one.add(Or(Tie, Shirt))

s_two = Solver()
s_two.add(Or(Not(Tie), Shirt))

s_three = Solver()
s_three.add(Or(Not(Tie), Not(Shirt)))

s_four = Solver()
s_four.add(s_one.assertions(), Or(list(s_two.assertions()) + list(s_three.assertions())))

print(s_four.sexpr())
```

This prints:

```
(declare-fun Shirt () Bool)
(declare-fun Tie () Bool)
(assert (or Tie Shirt))
(assert (or (not Tie) Shirt (not Tie) (not Shirt)))
```